# inservt database value into date form field

Tags: php, forms, date

I've created a form so I can update a database table. Everything's working (text, file, select, radio) except my date form fields.

Empty, they show the default date placeholder text: mm/dd/yyyy. I can insert a value manually:

```
<input name="iu_received" type="date" class="form-control" id="iu_received" value="2022-09-20">
```

And that will show as 09/20/2022 on the page.

However, trying to insert a value from my database recordset doesn't do anything and the placeholder text still displays. For example:

```
<label class="form-label mb-0">Date Distributed:</label> <input type="date" class="form-control" name="iu_distrib" value="<?php echo $rsAppl->getColumnVal("iu_distrib"); ?>">
```

(Yes, the "iu_distrib" value is a mysql date: 2022-09-20.)

How can I make this work?

Comment: Have you checked what the actual HTML code this produced, looks like?

Comment: PHP doesn't have access to the browser, all it sees is the HTTP request payload. And you can't generally inject free-format untrusted input into a database date column, you need some kind of validation and/or parsing.